# H2 'AS' Column alias error

Tags: sql, oracle, h2

So here is the H2 table schema:

```
drop table IF EXISTS

CREATE TABLE CAR_SPEED
(
  ACC_RATE                      VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL,
  SPEED_GROUP                   VARCHAR2(30) NOT NULL,
  MAX_SPEED                     NUMBER,
  MIN_SPEED                     NUMBER       
);
```

The query statement I tried to execute was this:

```
SELECT distinct MAX_SPEED as limit
FROM CAR_SPEED  
WHERE ACC_RATE ='Full' 
AND SPEED_GROUP = 'CS';
```

When I run this exact same query in oracle I have no issues but when I ran on h2 I got the following error

```
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Syntax error in SQL statement "SELECT DISTINCT MAX_SPEED AS LIMIT[*]
FROM CAR_SPEED 
WHERE CAR_SPEED 
AND SPEED_GROUP = 'CS' "; expected "identifier"; SQL statement:
SELECT DISTINCT MAX_SPEED AS LIMIT[*]
FROM CAR_SPEED 
WHERE CAR_SPEED 
AND SPEED_GROUP = 'CS' [42001-160]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:329)
```

If I remove the 'AS LIMIT' from the query it will run fine, but when I keep it in, it give me this syntax error. Does anyone have any idea why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`limit` is a [reserved word](http://www.h2database.com/html/advanced.html). Use another one or escape it with double quotes.

Comment: it is reserved in oracle? or h2? it is the h2 that was giving me the problem

Comment: It is reserved in most DB engines, also in H2 and Oracle.